# onChange does not redirect to URL

Tags: javascript, url

I have the following form select:

```
<select name="category" onChange="top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" onSubmit="top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"  value="GO">

<input value="Go" type="submit">
```

That operates with the

```
<option value="http://yourdomain.com/?query=&category=jacksonville">Jacksonville</option>
```

The onChange element works fine and redirects to the correct URL but when I click submit the redirect does not work and simply appends to the end of the URL.  I've tried to combine the two events and that breaks both actions.

When submit is clicked it does this:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/classifieds/?category=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F%3Fquery%3D%26category%3Dpanama-city
```

Comment: I'm assuming your input submit button is inside a form? Have you tried `e.preventDefault()` as the first line of code in your submit function?

Comment: use form in html to redirect on form submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onSubmit property should be given in the form and the onChange on an input element see the example below that will work for you:

```
<select name="category" onChange="top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="http://yourdomain.com/?query=&category=jacksonville">Jacksonville</option>
<option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
<option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
</select>
```

The above code will redirect upon the `onchange event` so you actually do not need on submit as upon changing the page will already redirect.

See below for the onSubmit example:

```
<form onSubmit="event.preventDefault();top.location.href=document.getElementById('domains').options[document.getElementById('domains').selectedIndex].value;">
<select name="category" id="domains">
<option value="http://yourdomain.com/?query=&category=jacksonville">Jacksonville</option>
<option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
<option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
</select>
<input value="Go" type="submit">
</form>
```

Here we redirect on the form submit function.

**UPDATE**

The reason why we use `event.preventDefault();` is to prevent the default form submission and to perform the operation we provided. i.e to redirect. to the selected URL.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco Please check the updated answer, the second code. I have added `event.preventDefault();` to the form onSubmit attribute, which helps to stop the form form from doing its default submit and perform the operations we gave. Please check, it is working now